# Missing properties of database when imported into VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access-2013

i have a MS Access database with two tables. one of the columns `Status` has fixed choices `ACTIVE` and `COMPLETED` and the column `OrderNumber` is auto generated but as you can see i can enter any number i want.
However when added this database to my VB.NET ( i am using Visual Basic 2010 Express ) these properties have been left out.
i am new to vb.NET and frankly i don't even know what terms to use for searching for such a problem.

[image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDEK9.png)

[image of vb application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx1zE.png)

Comment: Is the Status field a text type and you are saving the actual words 'ACTIVE' and 'COMPLETED'? OrderNumber is autonumber field - how can you enter any number you want?

Comment: the `Status` field is a short text type and using lookup wizard i configured it to accept only 'ACTIVE' and 'COMPLETED' values. also `OrderNumber` is indeed autonumber field.
as my question states these settings are not working when i import database into vb.net application.

Comment: So the lookup is sourced by Value List? Sorry, I am at a loss to explain either of these issue.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822458/creating-tables-in-access-using-vb-net Maybe it can help

Comment: thanks, i guess i'll have to code the table creation. maybe it doesn't work when importing into vb.net